# How to list_objects in aiobotocore not recursively

Tags: python-3.x, minio

I have the following code for getting a list of objects.

```
paginator = self.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
async for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix):
      for file in result.get('Contents', []):
          yield file
```

What do I need to add to display objects in only one directory, without recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Delimiter='/'` kwarg

```
paginator = self.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
async for result in paginator.paginate(
    Bucket=bucket_name, 
    Prefix=prefix, 
    Delimiter='/',
):
    for file in result.get('Contents', []):
         yield file
```